# Distributing n distinct objects to r different people - Why is my method wrong?

Tags: combinatorics

I saw this problem:
*How do I distribute 5 different candies to 3 different students?*

I decided to try and make a modified **Stars and Bars** formula to handle the different candies.

My Method:

Suppose I had 5 different candies:
*A B C D E*

and 2 bars for 3 different students: *||*

combined: *A B C D E | |*

To find all the different combinations of candies and students, I need to do

$${\frac{7!}{2!}}$$

However, my answer was wrong. I'm not sure what the correct answer is, because the quiz I took did not show it.

Why is my method wrong?

Comment: Stars and Bars works if the objects are identical.  As they are distinct, each object can go to any of the three students  so...

Comment: the candies are indistinguishable

Comment: yes I know but this isn't exactly stars and bars. I modified it by removing 5!

Comment: In the way you are thinking, take example of a student getting all $5$ candies. You are going to permute that and consider all of them different. That is quite a bit of overcounting.

Comment: @ironX: No, they are not: they are explicitly stated to be different.

Comment: @MathLover thank you for your reply, i understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just have to affect one student to each candy. For each candy, you have $3$ different possibilities, so this gives
$$3^5=243$$
possibilities.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer! can you help me understand why my answer is incorrect?

Comment: In your solution, $AB|C|DE$ is not the same as $BA|C|DE$ whereas it should be.

Comment: ah okay i see thank you!